Using Server index.html file is not loading in Android but loading in ios on flutter
type here

final String serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
var indexPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path+"/resources/index.html";

void runLocalHost() async {
server.InAppLocalhostServer localhostServer = server.InAppLocalhostServer();
if (!localhostServer.isRunning()) {
await localhostServer.start();
}
}
var webView = Scaffold(
body: Column(children: \<Widget\>\[Expanded(child:
server.InAppWebView(
initialUrlRequest: server.URLRequest(
url: WebUri(serverUrl+indexPath)
),

This is my AndroidManifest file
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <application
        android:label="wanted_slots"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        >
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
            android:value="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="codegenit.org" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="codegenit.org" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

I want to load the index.html file in android i am loading the index.html file in inAppWebview but it is only loading in ios not in android. in android showing the white screen so i want to laod the index.html. for running localhost i am useing inapplocalhost and for loading the index file i am using inappwebveiw.
