Switch automatically turn off by itself
I tried to use a bottom navigation bar and included a switch component. Initially, I encountered an issue where the initialized variable couldn't be accessed. Following a recommendation from ChatGPT, I used final and implemented void initState to resolve this. However, I now face a new problem where the switch turns off automatically by itself.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//1 hour

class SecurityAlertsSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecurityAlertsSettings({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecurityAlertsSettings> createState() => _SecurityAlertSettingsState();
}

class _SecurityAlertSettingsState extends State<SecurityAlertsSettings> {
  late bool _push=false;
  late int _selectedIndex=4;
  late List<Widget> _pages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages = [
      Container(child: Text("Home"),),
      Container(child: Text("Portfolio"),),
      Container(child: Text("hehehehe"),),
      Container(child: Text("Prices"),),
      Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 14, 0, 16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Security alert(preview)",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.grey),),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                  Text("Your password has been reset",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0),),
                  Text("Jan 1",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.grey),)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
            Text("Get notified about important security alerts such as password resets",
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40,),
            Text("Preferences",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikMedium",fontSize: 22.0),),
            SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
            Text("Tell us how you'd like to be notified",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "GraphikRegular",fontSize: 16.0,color: Colors.grey),),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Push"),
                Switch(
                    value: _push,
                    onChanged: (bool value){
                      setState(() {
                        _push = value;
                      });
                    }
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      },)
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Security alerts settings"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0,vertical: 12.0),
        child: _pages[_selectedIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/NavBar/Home_fill.png",
              color: _selectedIndex==0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/NavBar/Pipe_fill.png",
              color: _selectedIndex==1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: "Portfolio"
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/NavBar/Group 105.png",
            ),
            label: ""
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset("assets/images/NavBar/Chart_alt_fill.png",
                color: _selectedIndex==3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: "Prices"
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset("assets/images/NavBar/User_fill.png",
                color: _selectedIndex==4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
              ),
              label: "Settings"
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've no idea since the Chatgpt keeps saying initialized the _push outside the initState, anyone knows how to solve it?

did you tried to set push = !push

_push is initialised as false so it will be in off state in the beginning. On click of your button it should turn on, or does it not?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78298175/using-server-index-html-file-is-not-loading-in-android-but-loading-in-ios-on-flu pls check my issue in flutter
@lvo

I've tried it @A-E , but still whenever I try to slide it, it automatically back to false value

It will but yeah but it automatically back to turn off again @ClevinoAlrin

The problem arises because of declaring the pages outside of the build method. While the page does rebuild when calling setState the pages don't because it doesn't know it has to. One way to solve it is to use a StatefulBuilder. Simply replacing the line
  Builder(builder: (context) {

with
  StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {

will solve it. Because then it will use the builder's setState instead then when clicking the switch. But ideally you'd want each page in a separate file as their own StatefulWidget and their own state.

ahh I see thank you very much for the advice, honestly I haven't learnt about the bottomnavbar in just depending on the youtube channel, so I still don't know how to make it in a separate file. Thank you very much btw for the advice I really appreciate it
